# Get associated records with Datamapper using Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I am currently working on a small backend, managing events with associated locations. Unfortunately, it's my first time i work with Ruby/Sinatra/Datamapper. After 3 hours trying to find a solution, i have to write this post.

I have defined two Resources:

```
class Event
  include DataMapper::Resource  
  property :id,                  Integer, :key => true 
  property :name,                 Text 
  property :description,          Text 

  has 1, :location
end


class Location
  include DataMapper::Resource 

  property :id,                  Integer, :key => true 
  property :name,                 Text 
  property :latitude,             Float
  property :longitude,            Float    

  belongs_to :event 
end
```

This is my route to list all events:

```
get "/events/" do  
  @events = Event.all

  content_type :json
  @events.to_json
end
```

Is there a easy way the get the location as a parameter in the output of the associated event object?

**Thank you very much for your support!**

Comment: Do you mean something like Event.where(:location.name => routeparameter) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer by myself when i took a deeper look at the to_json options

```
@events.to_json(:relationships=>{:location=>{}})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-migrations'
require 'dm-sweatshop' # for fixtures
require 'json'

DataMapper::Logger.new($stdout, :debug)
DataMapper.setup(:default, 'sqlite::memory:')

class Event
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial # will automatically become an auto-increment key
  property :name, String # defaults to being max 50 char length
  property :description, Text, :lazy => false # defaults to true
  belongs_to :location # instead of one-to-one relation, which are rarely useful
end

class Location
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String
  property :latitude, Float # perhaps decimal with less precision would suffice
  property :longitude, Float
  has n, :events
end

DataMapper.finalize.auto_migrate!

# Define some fixtures to have some data to play around with
def rand_float(min, max); rand * (max - min) + min end

Location.fix {{
  :name => /\w+/.gen,
  :latitude => rand_float(40.0, 43.0),
  :longitude => rand_float(4.8, 5.4)
}}

Event.fix {{
  :name => /\w+/.gen,
  :description => /[:sentence:]/.gen[5..100],
  :location => Location.pick
}}

100.of { Location.gen; Event.gen }

# Search events by properties of its association
get "/events/:location_name" do |location_name|
  @events = Event.all(Event.location.name => location_name)
  @events.to_json
end

# Return both objects in the same array
get "/events/" do
  @events = Event.map {|e| [e, e.location] }
  @events.to_json
end
```